# How to sign up for services that are banning you? (because of Tor?)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

I have tried to sign up for a few services/accounts, most recently on http://forums.debian.net and was pretty much denied with messages like:

IP Address 78.108.63.44 is listed in the CBL. It appears to be infected with a spam sending trojan, proxy or some other form of botnet.
It was last detected at 2014-03-26 07:00 GMT (+/- 30 minutes), approximately 5 hours ago.
This IP address is infected with, or is NATting for a machine infected with the ZeuS trojan, also known as "Zbot" and "WSNPoem".

I got similar messages for each of the 4 times I tried a new identify and tried to re-sign up. This is a bit frusterating and I was wondering if there is some way around this without compromising my anonymity?

Comment: Have you tried contacting any of these places? You could point out how blindly blocking Tor harms numerous innocent users in order to stop a few abusers. It's quite funny, given how popular Debian seems to be among Tor folk, to see their forums blocking Tor exits.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to tunnel through another proxy or VPN. In that case however, depending on the actual use case and situation it might make sense to just connect to the VPN and not through Tor.

Comment: Using just a VPN service instead of Tor would compromise OP's anonymity, albeit not entirely. Even tunneling VPNs through Tor can compromise anonymity. VPN accounts must be set up via Tor, and either free or purchased anonymously.